# Interface Error of mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-connector

I installed mysql *connector/python* and am using MAMP. When I try to connect to a database,this is what comes up in the terminal :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "database.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise_on_warnings= True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
        return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 719, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 475, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:8889:3306' (60 Operation timed out)
```

I tried going into the *connector folder* and checked out the network.py script and it seems the error is due to Interface Error. The documentation says:

> This exception is raised for errors originating from Connector/Python itself, not related to the MySQL server.
>
> errors.InterfaceError is a subclass of errors.Error

Here's my python script if required:

```
import mysql.connector

con = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
                              password ='root',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='testdb',
                              raise_on_warnings= True)

cur = con.cursor()

cur.close()
con.close()
```

How to get rid of the interface error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the port and colon sign from your host:

```
 con = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
                               password ='root',
                               host='localhost',
                               database='testdb',
                               raise_on_warnings= True)
```

Your port is already set to 3306

Comment: gives the same error except gives a **61 Connection refused** instead of **60 Operation timed out**.. Could it be because the database may no longer exist and so i should install MAMP first?

Comment: if you're using localhost you need to make sure your mamp is running and localhost is actually there and ports are ready.

Comment: tried. still the same error with **61 Connection refused**.

Comment: See if your mysql is actually running - looks like there's timeout issue, so verify your mysql is actually up, or start it if not - use terminal or any mac client.

Comment: it is up. The mysql port is set to 8889,would it be ok to change it to 3306? i think i should just try installing mysqldb or something like pypi..would you suggest that? Thanks a lot for the help though!

Comment: Yes, and then just restart it, otherwise you have to add port to your connection code host='localhost',port='8889' - either way

Comment: changing the mysql port number solved everything! Thank you! :)